# Prevent app from returning to BootActivity when Home is pressed on the navigation bar

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, android-lifecycle

I am building an Android application that launches 3rd party applications - both of which run in full screen.

When the 3rd party application is launched, if i swipe up from the bottom, i see the Android navigation bar (good) - however, if i then press the Android Home button on this nav bar, the 3rd party application exits (good), but my application is returned to the main boot activity and not the activity from which i launched the application from.

My application manifest contains..

```
<activity android:name=".boot.BootActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|locale|layoutDirection"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity android:name=".main.MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|locale|layoutDirection"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
```

The BootActivity performs a bunch of pre-loading and model generation before waiting for the user to select a button which starts loading MainActivity which displays the menus and synopsis for the 3rd party apps.

When 3rd party is launched, we swipe up and press Home on the Android nav bar, the logcat is getting both "android.intent.action.MAIN" and "android.intent.category.HOME".

As mentioned above, this is causing the app to return to the boot activity - but i would like the 3rd party app to exit and return to the apps synopsis in MainActivity.

Can intent-filters be added, removed or temporarily disabled programmatically?

Comment: Brother, it is a problem of OS Ram space that how your device is capable to handle your third party app you are doing a heavy task on second activity than you have to handle your data savedInstance() & restoreInstance() & onResume() & onPause()  otherwise it will go to direct the first activity based on intent filer

Answer (score 0):

Generally using these special launch modes (`singleTask`) is a bad idea. If your `BootActivity` is launching `HomeActivity`, then this will not run in a new task, even though the launch mode would imply that, because these activities both have the same `taskAffinity`. If you really want to have them run in different tasks, then you need to set the `taskAffinity` of one or the other (or both) so that they are not the same. Read a bit about how `taskAffinity` works.